# How to add a JSON dictionary to realm with AlamofireObjectMapper

Tags: json, swift2, realm, alamofire

I am trying to add my JSON objects to Realm but I keep being thrown this error

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x10c52f178) to 'NSArray' (0x10c52eb88).

at line `for user in result as! [AnyObject] {`. This is my JSON response:

```
{
  "name" : "Jonny Walker",
  "api_token" : "qwertyuiop1234567890",
  "profile_picture" : "http:default_profile_picture.jpg",
  "id" : 10,
  "email" : "jwalker@gmail.com"
  "username" : "jonny"
}
```

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper


class Login {

init(userName: String, passWord: String) {
    Data.sharedInstance.userName = userName
    Data.sharedInstance.passWord = passWord
}

// call this method to login
func getRequest() {

let parameters = [
        "username" : Data.sharedInstance.userName!,
        "password" : Data.sharedInstance.passWord!,
    ]

Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.todoEndpoint, parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in


if let result = response.result.value
{
   let value = JSON(result)
   do{        
     print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
     let realm = try! Realm()
     for user in result as! [AnyObject] {
         try realm.write{
            realm.add(user as! Object, update: true)
         }
     }

   }

   catch let err as NSError {
      print("Error with realm: " + err.localizedDescription)
   }

}
else
{
  print("JSON data is nil.")
}

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you receive only **one** user instead of many. In this case you should try to parse your response to an Array, if it fails try to map it to an single User Object...

Don´t use "as!". Use "as?" instead and test for nil.

Example:

```
let dict = response as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

if dict != nil {
    // Parse a single User
} else {
    let arr = response as? [AnyObject]
}
```

Comment: How do I map it to a single user object?

Comment: I don´t know. I think you can create a new User with `let user = User()` and set your properties from the dictionary. E.g.: user.name = dict["name"] as? String